# This site can’t be reached i am trying to open the but its not opening

Tags: dns, typo3, probe

[image]

This site can’t be reached. Check if there is a typo in reblogin.com.
If spelling is correct, try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Comment: @novonimo. No. The question as it stands is offtopic here and shouldn't get comments or answers, just get closed.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek thank you, it was a silly mistake for me, I removed my comments and flag the topic to just close.

Answer (score 0):

DNS-Check by [IntoDNS](https://intodns.com/reblogin.com) is telling:

```
ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond: The ones that
did not respond are:
159.69.209.206
```

That IP is the used `ns1.tezhost.com`.